# How to change style of html with js inject?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

Here is my content of webview:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
          body{
              font-size:32pt;
              text-align:justify;
              color:#ffffff;
              font-family:Arial;
              background:#000000;
           }
           img{
              display: inline;
              height: auto;width: 100%;
           }
           h4{
              align: center;
              text-align: center;
           }
       </style> 
    </head>

    <h4> ..... </h4>
    <body>
        <!--<p>-->
        ...........
        <!--</p>-->
    </body> 
</html>
```

I want to change some value of style in the content. I try to use:

```
contentWV.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {
    document.head.style.fontSize='"+ Settings_Static.fontSize + "pt';
})()");
```

But it's not a success. I'm not a JS member, please help me the correct JS code to change the theme here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the body, not the head:

```
document.body.style.fontSize = '32px';
```

Comment: Thankyou, that is the answer for me. I don't think that is body